# irregular ticks on y2 axis

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the a [simple gnuplot code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ms6VJHiU) to generate the following plot:

[image: plot]

How do I make the irregular ticks on the y2 axis go away?

It seems like one of the columns is causing this issue. I would like to use just one column (any one between column 3 and 6) for y2. The data for the plot is also available [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sWxaduSC).

Answer (score 2):

I can't see the code you used to produce the plot, but what you probably want is the command

```
set ytics nomirror
```

This will prevent the tics on the left axis from being mirrored on the right.